# Embedding Youtube videos in ExpandableListView child

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-youtube-api

I want to embed YouTube videos in my ExpandableListView. That is, when each object is pressed, I want a YouTube video to show underneath.

I already accomplished this functionality with local videos and a VideoView, but since the APK ended up being too big, I decided to just stream the videos instead.

With my VideoView implementation, the adapter for the ExpandableListView set the URI path for each child item.

However, since Youtube videos should be played using the Android Youtube API, I tried looking into that. However, the examples I've seen just have one or two fixed YoutubeViews and the activity/fragment initialize them. In my case, I want them to be dynamically initialized when the parent item is selected.

Any ideas?